# If "Run as administrator" can be used without entering a password, am I a full administrator in Win 7?

Tags: windows-7, uac, administrator

If "Run as administrator" can be used without entering a password, am I a full administrator in Win 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a password if you are not an administrator. So yes you are an admin.

> NOTE: If you are doing this is while
>   logged in as standard user instead of
>   an administrator, then you will need
>   to provide the administrator's
>   password before the program will run
>   as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

By default in windows 7 you run as a standard user whether or not you are part of the administrators group.  You only elevate to full admin(run as administrator) when an application needs to access resources that require more permissions.